# The concept of convexity of a function with respect to a variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-geometry, linearization

Suppose that we have a function $L$ which is related to $\lambda$ and $\eta$ as follows:

$$L = \lambda + \rho(\eta - \bar{\eta})$$

where $\rho$ and $\bar\eta$ are constants.

It is said that the values of $\rho$ greater than zero implies convexity of $L$ with respect to eta. What does that mean exactly? I couldn't find a reasonable definition in the literature.

Comment: What are $\lambda$ and $\eta$? Other functions? Constants?

Comment: Actually, what I am searching is just the meaning of this statement "convexity of LL with respect to eta". Maybe you can explain it to me by exemplifying something simpler.

Comment: The statement does not have any meaning without the context. Linear functions are convex, which is why the part "values of $\rho$ greater than zero" does not make any sense.